# Get a workable URL from Python Get request

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm scraping a JS loaded website using requests. In order to do so, I go to inspect website, network console and look for the XHR calls to know where is the website calling for the data and how. Process would be as follows

Go to the link `https://www.888sport.es/futbol/#/event/1006276426` in Chrome. Once that is loaded, you can click on many items with an unique ID. After doing so, a pop up window with information appears. In the XHR call I mentioned above you get a direct link to get this information as follows:

```
import requests
url='https://eu-offering.kambicdn.org/offering/v2018/888es/betoffer/outcome.json?lang=es_ES&market=ES&client_id=2&channel_id=1&ncid=1586874367958&id=2740660278'

#ncid is the date in timestamp format, and id is the unique id of the node clicked
response=requests.get(url=url,headers=headers)
```

Problem is, this isn't user friendly and require python. If I put this last url in the Chrome driver, I get the information but in plain text, and I can't interact with it. Is there any way to get a workable link from the request so that manually inserting it in a Chrome driver it loads that pop up window directly, as a regular website?

Answer (score 0):

You've to make the requests as `.json()` so you receive a `json` `dict`, which you can access it with `keys`.

```py
import requests
import json


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    print(r.keys())
    hview = json.dumps(r, indent=4)
    print(hview) # here to see it in nice view.


main("https://eu-offering.kambicdn.org/offering/v2018/888es/betoffer/outcome.json?lang=es_ES&market=ES&client_id=2&channel_id=1&ncid=1586874367958&id=2740660278")
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['betOffers', 'events', 'prePacks'])
{
    "betOffers": [
        {
            "id": 2210856430,
            "closed": "2020-04-17T14:30:00Z",
            "criterion": {
                "id": 1001159858,
                "label": "Final del partido",
                "englishLabel": "Full Time",
                "order": [],
                "occurrenceType": "GOALS",
                "lifetime": "FULL_TIME"
            },
            "betOfferType": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Partido",
                "englishName": "Match"
            },
            "eventId": 1006276426,
            "outcomes": [
                {
                    "id": 2740660278,
                    "label": "1",
                    "englishLabel": "1",
                    "odds": 1150,
                    "participant": "FC Lokomotiv Gomel",
                    "type": "OT_ONE",
                    "betOfferId": 2210856430,
                    "changedDate": "2020-04-14T09:11:55Z",
                    "participantId": 1003789012,
                    "oddsFractional": "1/7",
                    "oddsAmerican": "-670",
                    "status": "OPEN",
                    "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2740660284,
                    "label": "X",
                    "englishLabel": "X",
                    "odds": 6750,
                    "type": "OT_CROSS",
                    "betOfferId": 2210856430,
                    "changedDate": "2020-04-14T09:11:55Z",
                    "oddsFractional": "23/4",
                    "oddsAmerican": "575",
                    "status": "OPEN",
                    "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2740660286,
                    "label": "2",
                    "englishLabel": "2",
                    "odds": 11000,
                    "participant": "Khimik Svetlogorsk",
                    "type": "OT_TWO",
                    "betOfferId": 2210856430,
                    "changedDate": "2020-04-14T09:11:55Z",
                    "participantId": 1001024009,
                    "oddsFractional": "10/1",
                    "oddsAmerican": "1000",
                    "status": "OPEN",
                    "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED"
                }
            ],
            "tags": [
                "OFFERED_PREMATCH",
                "MAIN"
            ],
            "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED"
        }
    ],
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 1006276426,
            "name": "FC Lokomotiv Gomel - Khimik Svetlogorsk",
            "nameDelimiter": "-",
            "englishName": "FC Lokomotiv Gomel - Khimik Svetlogorsk",     
            "homeName": "FC Lokomotiv Gomel",
            "awayName": "Khimik Svetlogorsk",
            "start": "2020-04-17T14:30:00Z",
            "group": "1\u00aa Divisi\u00f3n",
            "groupId": 2000053499,
            "path": [
                {
                    "id": 1000093190,
                    "name": "F\u00fatbol",
                    "englishName": "Football",
                    "termKey": "football"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2000051379,
                    "name": "Bielorrusa",
                    "englishName": "Belarus",
                    "termKey": "belarus"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2000053499,
                    "name": "1\u00aa Divisi\u00f3n",
                    "englishName": "1st Division",
                    "termKey": "1st_division"
                }
            ],
            "nonLiveBoCount": 6,
            "sport": "FOOTBALL",
            "tags": [
                "MATCH"
            ],
            "state": "NOT_STARTED",
            "groupSortOrder": 1999999000000000000
        }
    ],
    "prePacks": []
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have covered the part of accesing the data. What I want is an url that displays it directly in a browser as a regular webpage does without having to use the previous link and manually click on the element with that id